# How to create an animated email input when user clicks on it using CSS

Tags: html, css, forms, input, design-patterns

I want to create a cool animation that when the user clicks on the email input or the password the label of the input will go up and have a nice transition in the bottom border.

**This is what I have:**

[image: This is what I have]

**And this is what I want to create:**

[image: This is what I want to create]

My code:

```css
.form {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.input {
  background: none;
  color: #c6c6c6;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  padding: 1.6rem;
  display: block;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #c6c6c6;
  width: 100%;
}

.label {
  position: absolute;
  color: #c6c6c6;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  left: 0.5rem;
  top: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="form">
    <input class="email input" type="email" name="email" />
    <label class="label" for="email">Email Address</label>
</div>
<div class="form">
    <input class="password input" type="password" name="password" />
    <label class="label" for="password">Password</label>
</div>
```

I've searched a lot but every code example I found was with SCCS, SASS and I don't understand it. So please help me with plain CSS. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created an animated demo using HTML and CSS.

```css
.main {
    width: 500px;
    margin: 50px 100px;
    ;
}

.form-group {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 45px;
}

input {
    display: block;
    width: 300px;
    font-size: 14pt;
    padding: 10px;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

input:focus {
    outline: none;
}

label {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 5px;
    color: #999;
    font-size: 14pt;
    font-weight: normal;
    pointer-events: none;
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

input:focus ~ label,
input:valid ~ label {
    top: -20px;
    font-size: 10pt;
    color: #5264AE;
}

.bar {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 320px;
}

.bar:before,
.bar:after {
    content: "";
    height: 2px;
    width: 0;
    bottom: 1px;
    position: absolute;
    background: #5264AE;
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

.bar:before {
    left: 50%;
}

.bar:after {
    right: 50%;
}

input:focus ~ .bar:before,
input:focus ~ .bar:after {
    width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="email" required />
        <span class="highlight"></span>
        <span class="bar"></span>
        <label for="email">Email</label>
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="password" name="password" required />
        <span class="highlight"></span>
        <span class="bar"></span>
        <label for="password">Password</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! But can you help understanding what that means ? input:focus ~ label

Comment: Yes, definitely

Comment: You could scope the 'focus' and 'height' label by simply 

useful : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I attached your code modified to work as intended, you can change any value to customize as you want but here's an explanation of how it works:

#### Input element

I added a `z-index` so that the user can click where the label is positioned and click the input instead of the label itself, also added a transition to make the animation smooth.

**input:focus** refers when input is active (user click or selected by pressing tab key).

And here's where the magic happens and the explanations of complex selectors:

```
.input:focus~.label,
.input:not([value=""]):not(:focus):invalid~.label,
.input.has-content~.label {
    font-size: .7rem;
    top: -.4rem;
    color: blue;
}
```

**.input:focus ~ .label** selects all input's element siblings with the class `.label` when input is *focus* so that when user focus in the input the label'll be above.

**.input:not([value=""]):not(:focus):invalid~.label** this selector'll catch when user unfocus the input but it got content, so the label don't goes down and overlap with the username. (as the password type input doesn't have value attribute I attach you a Js snippet that do the same trick for password element, simply adding the class `has-content` to the element)

Hope it helps you!

```js
document.querySelector('.password').oninput = (e) => {
  e.target.value.length > 0 ?
    e.target.classList.add('has-content') :
    e.target.classList.remove('has-content')
}
```

```css
.form {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 1rem;
}

.input {
  height: 20px;
  background: none;
  color: #c6c6c6;
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding: .5rem .7rem;
  display: block;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #c6c6c6;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}

.input:focus {
  outline: transparent;
  border-color: blue;
}

.input:focus~.label,
.input:not([value=""]):not(:focus):invalid~.label,
.input.has-content~.label {
  font-size: .7rem;
  top: -.4rem;
  color: blue;
}

.label {
  position: absolute;
  color: #c6c6c6;
  font-size: 1rem;
  left: 0.5rem;
  top: .6rem;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="form">
  <input class="email input" type="email" name="email" />
  <label class="label" for="email">Email Address</label>
</div>
<div class="form">
  <input class="password input" type="password" name="password" />
  <label class="label" for="password">Password</label>
</div>
```